# Using MERGE INTO with Scope_IDENTITY

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, upsert

When `Merge into` does an `insert` with the following statement, `Scope_Identity` returns the correct surrogate key information. However when an `update` is performed both `Scope_Identity` and `@@Identity` return the *next* available surrogate key. And when I added the `output`, I get a null on both `update` and `insert`.

How do I return the surrogate key on both the `update` and the `insert`?

```
DECLARE @Surrogate_KEY bigint


MERGE INTO [dbo].[MyTable] ChangeSet
USING (SELECT   @NaturalKey1 AS NaturalKey1, 
                @NaturalKey2 AS NaturalKey2, 
                @NaturalKey3 AS NaturalKey3,
                @Surrogate_KEY AS Surrogate_KEY) CurrentSet
ON  ChangeSet.NaturalKey1 = CurrentSet.NaturalKey1 AND 
    ChangeSet.NaturalKey2 = CurrentSet.NaturalKey2 AND 
    ChangeSet.NaturalKey3 = CurrentSet.NaturalKey3      
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET blah, blah, blah 

WHEN NOT MATCHED 
    THEN INSERT VALUES
       (
        blah, blah, blah
       )

output CurrentSet.*, @Surrogate_KEY ;

 print @Surrogate_KEY
 print @@IDENTITY
 print SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `inserted` pseudo table in your [OUTPUT clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx):

```
DECLARE @Surrogate_KEY bigint


MERGE INTO [dbo].[MyTable] ChangeSet
USING (SELECT   @NaturalKey1 AS NaturalKey1, 
                @NaturalKey2 AS NaturalKey2, 
                @NaturalKey3 AS NaturalKey3,
                @Surrogate_KEY AS Surrogate_KEY) CurrentSet
ON  ChangeSet.NaturalKey1 = CurrentSet.NaturalKey1 AND 
    ChangeSet.NaturalKey2 = CurrentSet.NaturalKey2 AND 
    ChangeSet.NaturalKey3 = CurrentSet.NaturalKey3      
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET blah, blah, blah 

WHEN NOT MATCHED 
    THEN INSERT VALUES
       (
        blah, blah, blah
       )

output inserted.* ;
```

This returns whatever the values are in the table (for the affected rows) at the end of the statement.

Comment: Thank you, I knew I left something simple out!

Answer (score 9):

```
DECLARE @Id ...
--
MERGE
    dbo.Table AS Tgt
USING
    (
        SELECT
            <Keys>
    ) AS Src
    ON Src.<Keys> = Tgt.<Keys>
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
        <...>
        ,@Id = Tgt.Id
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT
    (
        ...
    )
    VALUES
    (
        ...
    )
;--
RETURN/SET/PRINT ISNULL(@Id, SCOPE_IDENTITY())
```

Comment: Love the simplicity of this approach!